# Is there a way to call custom method of Custom Role Provider class

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, roleprovider

I have created my own custom role provider class "SGI_RoleProvider" and configured properly.
Everything is working fine.

Suppose that I have added a public method say "SayHello()", then how can i call that. Because if i am using Roles then the method is not displayed. If i am forcefully using that Roles.SayHello() then compiler gives the error.

Any suggestion how can i call this. Because creating a new instance of SGI_RoleProvider is meaningless.

Thanks for sharing your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myProvider = Roles.Provider as SGI_RoleProvider;
myProvider.SayHello();
```

Supposing you have correctly defined your provider as the default Provider

Comment: thanks buddy! But even casting does not work here because Roles is a static class. By the way i m using c#.

Comment: I tested this code and it works, I am not casting the Roles class but the Provider property of the Roles class which is of type RoleProvider. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.provider.aspx. The code I wrote is C#, maybe you're using framework 2.0, so you can write
CustomProvider myProvider = Roles.Provider as CustomProvider;
myProvider.SayHello();
instead.
Good luck!

Comment: Great!!! Thanks uvita! It works. Actually I forget to use Provider property. I was casting Roles. Yes I was considering the code in VB.

Comment: Thanks Buddy ! have been looking for it Since Ages..:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like

```
((SGI_RoleProvider)Roles.Provider).SayHello();
```

One line syntax does it all.